PHP PDO fetchObject returns duplicated properties, half of them null
I'm trying to learn PHP and MySQL. I've got a database and some retrieval happening, but when I used fetchObject() I get 2 instances returned. First tried:
class Food {
  // Properties
  public $id;
  public $version;
  public $name;
  public $solid;
  public $servingtext;
  public $servingmeasure;
  public $servingamount;

  private function __construct__() {}

  public static function get_with_id ($dbconn,$id, $version) {
      $stmt = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Foods WHERE Id = :Id and Version = :Version;');
      $stmt->execute([':Id' => $id, ':Version' => $version]);
      return  $stmt->fetchObject(__CLASS__);
    //   return $answer;
   }

  // Methods
  function set_id($id){
    $this->id = $id;
  }
   etc. with sets and gets

Called with
require "./templates/header.php";

try 
{
    include __DIR__ . '../../connection.php';
    $conobj = new Connection();
    $dbconn = $conobj->get_connection();
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    error_log(__FILE__ . ':' . $t->getMessage());
    echo 'Connection Error ' . $t->getMessage();
}
require "./models/food.php";
$food = Food::get_with_id ($dbconn,2,0);
var_dump($food);

Result:
object(Food)#4 (14) { ["id"]=> NULL ["version"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL ["solid"]=> NULL ["servingtext"]=> NULL ["servingmeasure"]=> NULL ["servingamount"]=> NULL ["Id"]=> int(2) ["Version"]=> int(0) ["Name"]=> string(35) "Sanitarium Weet-Bix Blends Hi-Bran+" ["Solid"]=> int(1) ["ServingText"]=> string(28) "1 serving = 40g (2 biscuits)" ["ServingMeasure"]=> string(1) "g" ["ServingAmount"]=> int(40) }
There should be just 7 fields, but the first set are all NULL and then there's the object I'm hoping for.
I tried..
<?php
class Food {
  // Properties
  public $id;
  public $version;
  public $name;
  public $solid;
  public $servingtext;
  public $servingmeasure;
  public $servingamount;

  private function __construct__() {}

  // Methods
  function set_id($id){
    $this->id = $id;
  }

with
<?php
require "./templates/header.php";

try 
{
    include __DIR__ . '../../connection.php';
    $conobj = new Connection();
    $dbconn = $conobj->get_connection();
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    error_log(__FILE__ . ':' . $t->getMessage());
    echo 'Connection Error ' . $t->getMessage();
}
require "./models/food2.php";
$id = 2;
$version = 0;
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Foods WHERE Id = :Id and Version = :Version;');
$stmt->execute([':Id' => $id, ':Version' => $version]);
$food = $stmt->fetchObject('Food');
var_dump($food);

Same result. Then with the same Food class tried:
<?php
require "./templates/header.php";

try 
{
    include __DIR__ . '../../connection.php';
    $conobj = new Connection();
    $dbconn = $conobj->get_connection();
} catch (Throwable $t) {
    error_log(__FILE__ . ':' . $t->getMessage());
    echo 'Connection Error ' . $t->getMessage();
}
require "./models/food2.php";
$id = 2;
$version = 0;
$food = $dbconn->query('SELECT * FROM Foods WHERE Id = ' . $id . ' AND Version = ' . $version . ';')->fetchObject('Food');
var_dump($food);

Again, the result with 2 entries.
Please can someone help with why I'm getting the NULLs version first. I don't want or need it. Happy to be told it's a newbie error! I have had plenty of success retrieving arrays but would like to go down the OO path.
Thanks, Paul
PHP 8.1.30, MySQL 9.1.0 and NGINX 1.27.2 in a Docker container

Have a look at your capitalization: id isn't the same as Id.

"I get 2 instances returned" - where does this happen? I highly doubt that fetchObject is able to do that, as it cannot return two objects, nor an array of objects

fetchObject() generates the class and gives you the first 7 columns of null, as you added them on the class Food, and they default to NULL
// Your properties, they all get NULL
public $id;
public $version;
public $name;
public $solid;
public $servingtext;
public $servingmeasure;
public $servingamount;

then the fetchObject() injects more variables: the columns of the result query also turns into class properties and makes it seems like its has duplicated, but we can trace it from the results of the vardump().
id duplicates with Id
version duplicates with Version
name duplicates with Name
...
Make the public properties variables match the column names you get on your query. From id to Id, servingtext to ServingText, etc.
Or find a way to generate the class without using fetchObject().
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Removing the properties doesn't sound like a good idea. I'm not even sure it will still work when the inevitable step to PHP 8.2 is made. See: PHP 8.2: Dynamic Properties are deprecated.

I see, then make these class properties of Food match the casing and syntax of the retrieved , from id to Id and so one would remove duplication.

Yes, matching them seems the best way to go. Also, note that answering question containing basis typos isn't really what we do here. The question should be closed as: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". I know, some typos can be hard to trace and understand... but this one isn't all that difficult. Closing a question can be quite a shock to the person asking the question, but many questions here are closed.

@KIKOSoftware I'm very liberal in closing as typo, but I think this is complicated enough that an answer is reasonable.

Thank you for the very speedy replies. Having the properties match the case of the db columns fixed it in all three versions.

Happy to with thanks
